# CQRS. Что является Command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cqrs

Какова область ответственности command?
Например, регистрация пользователя :

1. Создаем пользователя
2. Получаем пользователя по email (нужен его id)
3. Создаем тикет на подтверждение почты
4. Отправляем на почту письмо
5. Получаем роль User
6. Добавляем новому пользователю роль User

Правильнее создать одну команду, типа SignUpCommand и в SignUpCommandHandler мы выполняем все действия или разделяем каждый пункт на отдельные команды и запросы?